# copy constructor in object declaration and return from function

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

can't we simply overload "=" operator to instead of using copy constructor in object declaration and  return from function ie in

```
someclass X = Y;
X=somefunction();
```

can I overload "=" operator in someclass and not provide a copy constructor.

Is there any case which requires both copy constructor and overloading "=" operator to avoid pointer variables from two seperate objects to point to same memory location?

Comment: Are you talking about a particular language?

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  Your example code already uses both the copy constructor (assuming `Y` is of type `someclass`) and `operator=`.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: "Is there any case which requires both copy constructor and overloading "=" operator ?"

Answer (score 1):

No, those are different concepts and both of them exist for performance reasons.

- Copy constructor is used when you create a *new* object (from an existing object).
- Assignment is used when the object *already exists* but you want to assign a new value to it.

If you provide one of them provide the other one as well.